# How to switch component showing with React and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a composed page with multiple components. Like the picture, I want to show Component B inside Component A. By default, when clicking on A, hide B and show C in the middle. After clicking again, it toggles to show B and hide C.

When C has been showing, also change the A's border color.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

import {
  ComponentA,
  ComponentB,
  ComponentC,
} from "~/components";

export const NewComponent: React.FC = ({
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentA>
        <ComponentB>B</ComponentB>
        <ComponentC>C</ComponentC>
      </ComponentA>
    </>
  );
};

const ComponentA = styled()`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    &:active {
      border-color: green;
      bordor: 1px solid;
    }
  `}
`;
```

I tried to use CSS to control the border color, it works with `background-color` but does not work for `border-color`. Also, I'm not sure if CSS can control the showing between Component B and component C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch the components you need to use the **useState** hook with a boolean state. Then add an event **onClick** on the **ComponentA** and you can toggle state with the hook.

This way you can handle the border color switching. Create an attribute for **ComponentA** (you can chose name yourself ) you can pass values as a props, and using **Ternary Operator** toggle the color.

**PS:** If you don't use typescript, you can remove this line `<{ color: "green" | "white" }>` for **ComponentA**.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const ComponentA = styled.div<{ color: "green" | "white" }>`
  padding: 3rem 7rem;
  border: 2px solid ${(props) => props.color};
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
`;

const DefaultStyle = styled.div`
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
`;
export const ComponentB = styled(DefaultStyle)`
  background-color: magenta;
`;
export const ComponentC = styled(DefaultStyle)`
  background-color: orange;
`;

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsActive(!isActive);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA color={isActive ? "green" : "white"} onClick={toggle}>
        {isActive ? (
          <ComponentC>Component C</ComponentC>
        ) : (
          <ComponentB>Component B</ComponentB>
        )}
      </ComponentA>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useState} from "react";

import {
  ComponentA,
  ComponentB,
  ComponentC,
} from "./components";

export const NewComponent: React.FC = ({
}) => {   

 const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState<boolean>(true);
            
              const toggle = () => {
                setIsShowing(current => !current);
              };
            
              return (
      <>
          <ComponentA>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
                  {isShowing &&  <ComponentB>B</ComponentB>} // if true
                  {!isShowing && <ComponentC>C</ComponentC>} // if false
                </div>
     
          </ComponentA> </>
    
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This way is awesome. I just need to move the button onclick event to ComponentA. For A's border color. Is there a good solution? Maybe CSS' `active` doesn't support `border-color`.

Answer (score 1):

1. bordor - you wrote it wrong. It's border
2. When you set border: 1px solid; then border-color: initial

You can set CSS: border: 1px solid green;